# Wild Characters in MS Graph API when fetching all the users info

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to pull all the users' info from Microsoft Graph, when I do `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/`, it doesn't pull `manager`, `directReports`, etc. For that, I'm making additional API calls to
`/beta/users/xxxx@xxx.com/directReports` and
`/users/xxxx@xxx.com/authentication/methods`

Is there a way to use wildcard characters in the above, so that it fetches the `directReports` information for all the users? I don't want to make call for each user and method, as our Org is very big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the relationships to get these details.

For getting all users `directReports` you can use the below graph call.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=directReports`

See this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships).

Comment: Thanks Shiva, the document is really helpful. Also there is a JSON representation given in the same page, can I fetch all those details with a single API call? or its just the reference?

Comment: is there a similar relationship, i can use for fetching authentication/methods (MFA) of all the users?

Comment: No, those are the only relationships you can use. To get the authentication methods you need to check for each user.